# Why are application server keys needed for web push notifications?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, push-api

I was going through the [Code Lab](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/codelabs/push-notifications/) for web push notifications, which mentions that application server keys (public and private key pair) are required.

Why do we need application server keys for push notifications? How can we generate them? Is it mandatory to have application keys in order to work with push notifications?

[See companion site to generate application server keys](https://web-push-codelab.appspot.com/)

Answer (score 5):

The documentation that you linked explicitly says how to generate the key, in the `Get Application Server Keys` paragraph.

Another way is to use the [web-push](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push) library (either by calling the [generateVAPIDKeys function](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push#generatevapidkeys) via some Node.js code or via its [command line interface](https://github.com/web-push-libs/web-push#command-line)).

Regarding the `why` and `how is it related to Web Push`, I think the abstract of the [VAPID specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-thomson-webpush-vapid-02) is quite clear:

> An application server can voluntarily identify itself to a push
> service using the described technique.  This identification
> information can be used by the push service to attribute requests
> that are made by the same application server to a single entity.
> This can used to reduce the secrecy for push subscription URLs by
> being able to restrict subscriptions to a specific application
> server.  An application server is further able include additional
> information the operator of a push service can use to contact the
> operator of the application server.

Comment: How can I generate application key myself?

Comment: What do you mean? I outlined two options that you can use to generate the key yourself :)

Comment: Hey @Marco, Where do i find these Application Server Keys? If i am building push notifications for my website. Would i get it from my firebase console?

Comment: You can generate the keys as my answer explains.